# jquery uploading plugin with progressbar for mac browsers

Tags: jquery, uploading

i'm looking for a jquery uploading plugin which has a progress bar and works on most common browsers, especially mac based browsers (ipad, macbook ..).
i've used ax-uploader which worked on firefox, but seems to fail on apple based browers, which results in incomplete files. 
i assume it has to do witch chunked uploading or bugs. 
unfortunately i have no ipad/mac for testing.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We used this one in a project, we developed and tested on mac browsers but not on iPad, I don't think you're able to upload files from iOS devices though.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

However, "mac" browsers are not the special case for uploading, you can install safari, chrome and firefox on windows. Both versions for mac and windows use the same engine. If it's failing on mac, I guess it may be another problem, not the browser.